# vts-tradefed gives error when multiple ADB devices are connected

Tags: android, python, adb, android-vts

Android vts-tradefed gives error when multiple ADB devices are connected:

07-01 11:23:20 E/ProcessHelper: Exception AttributeError: "'AndroidDevice' object has no attribute 'hal'" in
07-01 11:23:20 E/ProcessHelper: > ignored
07-01 11:23:20 E/ProcessHelper: Exception AttributeError: "'AndroidDevice' object has no attribute 'hal'" in > ignored

Ideas?

Comment: adb 1.0.40 seems to have this problem. When I moved to adb version 1.0.41 it works, it was able to find the device in vts-tradefed. Weird but true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adb 1.0.41 solved the problem for me. Even adb 1.0.39 works for this usecase but 1.0.40 seems to have the issue.